python format does not work when spark source
I wrote the file path and entered the date dynamically to find the corresponding file, but the path when spark was executed was wrong, the date was not replaced, and 'usercode' was displayed.
I tried formats and concat, and it can be printed correctly, but when I call sc.textFile,it it print a wrong result.
my python version is 3.12.0
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
what should I do now?

After formatting date, convert it to string and the concat it. + str(date_str) +

does not work,same result

please post your code as formatted text and not images so we can more easily reproduce your error. thanks!

thank guys,I already found the prolem that the pingo will not replace placeholder.Instead,it use {DATE} to get the date.I already report it to the pingo.
